# Is return value of a array "undefined" in React?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state, undefined

I know its basic but i am stuck with the following bug or error. Need help

I am trying to use simple array method to return value on console and on screen using basic methods in react but it is giving me **undefined** error on console.

Following are the code of React of APP.js.

```
import React from 'react'

function App(){

  const [employees, setemployees] = React.useState([{
    id: 1,
    fullName: "Bob Jones",
    designation: "JavaScript Developer",
    gender: "male",
    teamName: "TeamA"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fullName: "Jill Bailey",
    designation: "Node Developer",
    gender: "female",
    teamName: "TeamA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    fullName: "Gail Shepherd",
    designation: "Java Developer",
    gender: "female",
    teamName: "TeamA"
  }]);

console.log(employees.fullName)
  return( 
    <main>
        <h1>{employees.fullName}<h1/>
    </main>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Output:**
Console: Undefined
On Screen: empty

Need help how to solve this error.

I tried different known methods like moving into components but does not work. I am expecting to show data on screen and on console.

Comment: The objects in your array may have a fullName property, but the array won't.

Answer (score 2):

it must be error. because you can't access `employees.fullName`. it must be at least `employees[0].fullName` to access first object inside `employees` array.

```js
console.log(employees[0].fullName);
```

if you want to render all names as an h1 you can do this.

```js
{employees.map(employee => <h1 key={employee.id}>{employee.fullName}</h1>)}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to show all names as h1. I used the map method but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering is likely "Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined." This is because employees is an array of objects and not a single object, so trying to access a property like fullName directly on employees will not work.

To fix this, you need to loop over the employees array and render each individual employee. One way to do this is by using the map function to iterate over the array and create a new array of elements for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

```
employees[0].fullName
```

should do it

Can you please give more details? btw, have you tried to write something like:

```
<div>
 <ol> 
{employees.map(employee => { <li key={employee.fullName}>{employee.fullName}</li>)} 
</ol> 
</div>
```

Comment: I want to show all the names as h1. How can I do it. The map method is not working?